# Tried to implement the Nilakantha algorithm in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, pi

```
import math
from decimal import *

pi = Decimal(3)

two = 2
three = 3
four = 4

times = 10000

for c in range(times):
    pi += Decimal(4)/two * three * four
    pi -= Decimal(4)/two + 2 * three + 2 * four + 2 * three

    two += 2
    three += 2
    four += 4

print(pi)
```

It always returns 39983.4247879279112354716423
Any Idea, why this is not working?

Comment: What algorithm/formula are you trying to implement? That should be part of your question.

Comment: Also, note that `10 / 2 * 5` is 25, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Note parentheses in denominators and updating values twice per round

```
for c in range(times):
    pi += Decimal(4)/(two * three * four)
    two += 2
    three += 2
    four += 2
    pi -= Decimal(4)/(two * three * four)
    two += 2
    three += 2
    four += 2
```

Comment: @CantEvenDoThis Are you aware about marking answers as solution?